# Move an existing XP install into VMWare or Virtual PC

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-player, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have a computer that has a bunch of things on it that are pretty legacy. It's an old machine, but getting everything on it set up properly on another computer could take weeks, if it's even possible at all.

So, I was wondering about taking that existing XP installation and virtualizing it, running it within VMWare or Microsoft Virtual PC. That would allow me to run it on newer, much speedier machines without wasting time moving everything over.

Is this even possible to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had some success in the past using [VMWare Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/). There's a free version available for personal use (or at least there was when I downloaded it).

Comment: Cool. I'm downloading it now and will give it a try!

Comment: I've used this for both XP and server 2003 with success.  It takes a while depending on the size of the install, but it's well worth it if you need the VM.

Comment: +1 Have been using this to convery Acronis .tib files for use in VPC along with http://www.starwindsoftware.com/converter (Starwind 2V2 Converter) ) for old Win2000 and XP machines with great success.